# Classpath of a decompiled Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

So I'm not CS major or anything and I've been just poking around stuff to practice some Java skills I watched from a video. I know this isn't the major way to do it but please, let me.

So I extracted a .jar file of this: http://www.zenlunatics.com/quizcards/ (i also have its outright source version). It's open source. I used JD gui to get the source code and got everything in .java. However, once I imported it and tried to run it in Eclipse, it says there is "no main type."

I've searched around and it seems there has to be a public static ... String[] args and I don't see that in any of the generated .java files.

I tried searching about it on youtube and he's getting .class instead of .java files. So, say I renamed .jar to .zip and extracted class files, do I just edit the main .class and build? Any tips, please.

Thanks!

Comment: Look in the manifest file for the specified main class. It's in the META-INF folder. Note that just because it's in a jar file and available open source, does not guarantee that it came with a main method. It could simply be a library for use in your own program.

Comment: Are you sure it was an **application**? `Applets` and many other forms of Java code do not use `main` method as a point of entrance.

Comment: To do what you're trying to do you really need a pretty good basic understanding of the Java language, the compile process, and how files are managed in a Java environment.

Comment: I have 2 of them. Both are in the forms of executable Jar. One of the two has an explicit "source" version the author put up.

Comment: So, if it doesn't have a 'main' method, do I just go to the main classpath and add the 'String[] args' or what? how could i run it in Eclipse?

Comment: If you don't know what a `main` method is, you need to study up on your Java fundamentals a bit more.

Comment: No, I get it. From a .jar, how do you change the entry point?

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the source code download the `main` method is in the `QuizCards` class (`QuizCards.java`).

Since there is a source code download you should use that.